# What happens to Entity Framework state if a server reboots before and during DbContext.SaveChanges

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What happens in the following C# aspnet entity framework scenario. Aspnet C# with entity framework connecting to azure sql.

1. Call DbContext.SaveChanges()
2. Modify a table in entity framework
3. Call DbContext.SaveChanges()

What happens if the aspnet server reboots between step 2 and 3. Does it lose 100% of data that was modified in step 2?

What happens if the aspnet server reboots during step 3. Is it possible for only some of the data to be committed? Or is SaveChanges a transaction and either 100% of its committed, or none of it?

Comment: Is this a trick question? SaveChanges is a transaction. First question: yes, second: no

Comment: Ok we had an issue where during a server reboot half of the data was saved. We are trying to investigate why. It seems it must be due to another reason.